# GPS Module will not boot

Tags: gps, arduino

I have an antenova part no. M10382 that I am attempting to control with an Ethernet Arduino.  I can get the unit to send packets over its USB channel but not over the UART channel.  I have tried sending the unit CR/LF at 9600 baud with no result.

Has anyone used this module?

Answer (score 0):

This GPS module is 3.3v, are you giving it 3.3v power and 3.3v on the GPS rx pin? You may have fried the module (or that pin) if you plugged it directly into the Arduino.

Once you have it wired correctly (3.3v), then try [this excellent GPS library](http://arduiniana.org/libraries/tinygps/). Try the example code to debug your problem. You should only have to plug in 3.3v VCC, GND and finally the tx pin of the GPS into a digital input pin on the Arduino.

Good luck.